# Convert json to xml in php without an online converter

Tags: php, json, converters

I've been trying hard on this for a while now, but can't find a solution on how to convert json to xml in php by file_get_contents. I don't want to use an online converter but want to have it in my website root directory.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856833/is-there-some-way-to-convert-json-to-xml-in-php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345445/how-to-convert-json-to-xml-in-php

Please do a search before asking a question. =o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert JSON to array/object by using [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), once you have it inside array you can use any [XML Manipulation method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php) to build XML out of it.

For example you may build XML structure like this:

```xml
<array>
  <data name="atrribute1">string 1</data>
  <array name="array_atribute">
     <data name="attribute2">string 2</data>
     <data name="attribute2">string 2</data>
  </array>
</array>
```

By [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php), and method [`DOMDocument::createElement()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php)

```
class XMLSerialize {

    protected $dom = null;

    public function serialize( $array)
    {
        $this->dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
        $element = $this->dom->createElement('array');
        $this->dom->appendChild($element);
        $this->addData( $element, $array);
    }

    protected function addData( DOMElement &$element, $array)
    {
        foreach($array as $k => $v){
            $e = null;
            if( is_array( $v)){
                // Add recursive data
                $e = $this->dom->createElement( 'array', $v);
                $e->setAttribute( 'name', $k);       
                $this->addData( $e, $v);

            } else {
                // Add linear data
                $e = $this->dom->createElement( 'data', $v);
                $e->setAttribute( 'name', $k);
            }

            $element->appendChild($e);
        }

    }

    public function get_xml()
    {
         return $this->dom->saveXML();
    }
}
```